# Android: file deleted when app is reinstalled

Tags: android, file, emulation

I save the current state of the game in a file located in `getExternalFilesDir(null)`.  I noticed that on the emulator running Android 2.2 (API 8), this file gets deleted when the new version of the app is installed.  Shared Preferences stay intact.  On a phone running 4.4.4, the file also stays intact.  I'm using Android Studio.

I know that when the signature of the APK changes, all the data pertaining to the app has to be deleted -- but that would also affect Shared Preferences, so that's not the case here.

Does anyone know if that's normal behavior?  Maybe there is a setting in how the Android Studio reinstalls the APK?  Maybe there is a flag in the file creation function that I need to set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- What you see is the [expected/default behavior of `getExternalFilesDir`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)) :

  > *"This is like getFilesDir() in that these files will be deleted when the application is uninstalled"*

  For [kitkat there has been changes related to this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html#KITKAT), so it may be retaining the file with update. Instead of update, if you uninstall the app on 4.4.4, and then reinstall, it should have deleted the file (part of uninstall as mentioned in above quote).
- In general it is recommended you delete the file when you uninstall the app, if its specific to your app (game state/config or stats). So you may not want to rely or expect that there be a file from previous install.

Comment: OK.  From the descriptions, it is unclear that the change in KitKat would have this effect.  I thought it was only related to the READ/WRITE EXTERNAL permission.  I do want this file to be deleted if the program is uninstalled -- hence placing it in getExternalFilesDir().  I also want a user to have access to it: if there is a crash, I want them to be able to send me the latest game-save.  I would like this file to be retained if the app is REinstalled, so behavior in KitKat is perfect.  Oh well.